# TextColor of UILabel subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm making button changing style of needed labels, so I created my own class and using `appearance()` on that, but it is not working. What should I do to fix that?

I've tried the same what I've seen with UILabel class, but made my own subclass:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var SomeLabel: MyUILabel
    class MyUILabel: UILabel {}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyUILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

I expected to change color of all labels of class MyUILabel, but it doesn't work, only if I do this with common UILabel.

Comment: Appearance works just for new created labels. Compare: [Change UILabel's textColor in whole app using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051412/change-uilabels-textcolor-in-whole-app-using-swift)

Comment: How are you presenting this `ViewController`? Try to change appearance before `pushing/presenting` this `ViewController`

Comment: appearance is a static method and your code MyUILabel.appearance().textColor is nil. But when you directly use UILabel.appearance().textColor it works and i can see MyUILabel.appearance().textColor is still nil for some reason extended class does not get the red color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do below and this works. I have tested this on simulator.

MyUILabel

```
import UIKit

class MyUILabel : UILabel {

    static func setCustomColor(color: UIColor) {
        UILabel.appearance().textColor = color
    }
}
```

In ViewDidLoad have below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        MyUILabel.setCustomColor(color: UIColor.purple)
}
```